# Javascript Object Properties with condition

Tags: javascript

How can I create object with properties in javascript ?

Something like :

```
function translate() {
    this.city = function () {
        if (language == "English") {
            return "City";
        } else {
            return "Ville";
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use this :

```
translate.city
```

It return undefined...

Comment: `translate` is a function. It only executes its body when you **call** it. Then depending on *how* you call it, `this` will have a different value. Lastly, the value you assign to `this.city` is also a function, with has to be executed. Put differently: The code you wrote is not aligned with *how* you want to use it. Please provide a better example and explanation of your problem/goal.

Comment: If you just want to learn how to work with objects, have a look at the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: *also* where are you defining language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your object:

```
var myTranslate = new translate();
var city = myTranslate.city();
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
var translate = {
    city: function () {
        if (language == "English") {
            return "City";
        } else {
            return "Ville";
        }
    }
};
var city = translate.city();
```

If you want to be able to access the `city` property without calling it as a function and you are using ES5 or higher, you can define a getter method:

```
var translate = {};
Object.defineProperty(translate, "city", { 
    get: function () {
        if (language == "English") {
            return "City";
        } else {
            return "Ville";
        }
    }
});
console.log(translate.city);
```

Or yet another way of defining a getter (also requires ES5):

```
var translate = {
    get city() {
        if (language == "English") {
            return "City";
        } else {
            return "Ville";
        }
    }
};
console.log(translate.city);
```

And one more variation (provided by @vol7ron), which determines the `city` value when the object is created:

```
function Translate() {
    this.city = (function () {
        if (typeof language !== 'undefined' && language == "English") {
            return "City";
        } else {
            return "Ville";
        }
    }());
}

var translate = new Translate();
translate.city;  // "Ville"
```

Comment: Or maybe the OP wants `var translate = {city: language == "English" ? "City" : "Ville"};`. We don't really know.